# How to use cat in a pipe

Tags: bash, unix, pipe, cut, cat

I have the following command:

```
httpd.conf | grep AuthUserFile | cut -d" " -f4 | sed -e 's|["'\'']||g'
```

the output of this is:

```
/etc/httpd/secure/htpasswd.training
```

I did:

```
httpd.conf | grep AuthUserFile | cut -d" " -f4 | sed -e 's|["'\'']||g'| cat
```

However this just returned:

```
/etc/httpd/secure/htpasswd.training
```

I want to cat the contents of the file. How do I do this?

Comment: okay (sorry), but then add the 'cut' and 'cat' tags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Piping to `xargs cat` will pass stdin as an argument to `cat`, printing the file.

Alternatively try: `cat $( some command printing a filename )`.

Comment: Why does your alternative solution work? What is it doing, exactly?

Comment: @Josh It's [command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03), the same thing as ``cat `command` `` if that's more familiar to you. If the command inside `$()`'s standard output is `/etc/httpd/secure/htpasswd.training`, then the result of substitution is `cat /etc/httpd/secure/htpasswd.training`, which is a new command that prints the contents of the file.

Comment: Why a pipe without `xargs` doesn't work with `cat` like it works for ex. with `grep` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try surrounding your initial command with backticks as the argument to `cat`, like so:

```
cat `httpd.conf | grep AuthUserFile | cut -d" " -f4 | sed -e 's|["'\'']||g'`
```